# How to use String#split with a backslash character?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I would like to split this string:

```
C:\RCOUNT2013\2013_Extracted\Weekly ODEN Notices Report.12-28-2013.2013-12-29 07-20-51.pdf.log.0
```

on the `\`. What would the regex be?

```
string.split("\\ \")  // ?
```

Comment: I was trying to find a duplicate because this can be easily found on the net, but @arshajii's answer is good enough IMO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In regex-land, a `\` is an escape character, so to obtain a *literal* `\` we need to escape it: `\\`. However, in Java strings, `\` is *also* an escape character, so we need to escape each `\` a second time, resulting in `\\\\`. Therefore, this is what you want:

```
str.split("\\\\")
```

Comment: Voting this up because it is the only answer that explains the reasons to use four \

Comment: Why not five ? Do I hear six?

Answer (score 1):

The regex would be `"\\\\"`

In the source code: `"\\\\"`

After compiling, the string is: `"\\"`

And the regex parser interperets this as `look for a \`, So it matches one backslash `'\'`

Answer (score 0):

```
split("\\\\")
```

Double-escaping "\"