# How to split by escape character in java?

Tags: java

I have the following string:

```
c:\Users\moises\file
```

and I'm trying to use:

```
String fileName = path.split("\\")[3];
```

but I get this error:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1
```

How can I split the string with the "\" character

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23832593/139010

Comment: `new java.io.File(path).getName()`

Comment: Consider using the nio Path API instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
path.split("\\\\");
```

You need to escape your escapes

Answer (score 0):

You'll need four backslashes in a row.

The regular expression with then consist of two backslashes: that means a literal backslash.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is because you need to escape four times, try this:

`path.split("\\\\");`